# Failed Bitbucket NodeJS repo Pipeline with AWS Lambda function with "Error parsing parameter '--zip-file......' "

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, bitbucket-pipelines

Our team is having a problem trying to set up a pipeline for update an AWS Lambda function.

Once the deploy is triggered, it fails with the following error:

```
Status: Downloaded newer image for bitbucketpipelines/aws-lambda-deploy:0.2.3
INFO: Updating Lambda function.
aws lambda update-function-code --function-name apikey-token-authorizer2 --publish --zip-file fileb://apiGatewayAuthorizer.zip
Error parsing parameter '--zip-file': Unable to load paramfile fileb://apiGatewayAuthorizer.zip: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'apiGatewayAuthorizer.zip'
*Failed to update Lambda function code.
```

Looks like the script couldn't find the artifact, but we don't know why.

Here is the bitbucket-pipelines.yml file content:

```
    image: node:16
# Workflow Configuration
pipelines:
default:
 - parallel:
 - step:
name: Build and Test
caches:
 - node
script:
 - echo Installing source YARN dependencies.
 - yarn install

branches:
testing:
 - parallel:
 - step:
name: Build 
script:
 - apt update && apt install zip
# Exclude files to be ignored
 - echo Zipping package.
 - zip -r apiGatewayAuthorizer.zip . -x *.git* bitbucket-pipelines.yml

artifacts:
 - apiGatewayAuthorizer.zip
- step:
name: Deploy to testing - Update Lambda code
deployment: Test
trigger: manual
script:
 - pipe: atlassian/aws-lambda-deploy:0.2.3
variables:
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
FUNCTION_NAME: $LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME
COMMAND: 'update'
ZIP_FILE: 'apiGatewayAuthorizer.zip'
```

Does anyone knows what am I missing here?

Comment: Can you confirm that an artifact was indeed created?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, your pipeline looks identical to their tutorial (https://bitbucket.org/blog/aws-lambda-deployments-using-bitbucket-pipelines-and-pipes), except for one thing: they are demonstrating the pipe version 0.2.1. Did you try to use it too?

Comment: Thank you for your concern, we found the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Marc C. from Atlassian, here is the solution.

> Based on your YAML configuration, I can see that you're using Parallel
> steps.
>
> According to the documentation:
>
> > Parallel steps can only use artifacts produced by previous steps, not
> > by steps in the same parallel set.
>
> Hence, this is why the artifacts is not generated in the "Build" step
> because those 2 steps are within a parallel set.
>
> For that, you can just remove the parallel configuration and use
> multi-steps instead. This way, the first step can generate the
> artifact and pass it on to the second step. Hope it helps and let me
> know how it goes.
>
> Regards, Mark C

So we've tried the solution and it worked!.
Here is the new pipeline:

```
    pipelines:
  branches:
    testing:
        - step:
            name: Build and Test
            caches:
              - node
            script:
              - echo Installing source YARN dependencies.
              - yarn install
              - apt update && apt install zip
              # Exclude files to be ignored
              - echo Zipping package.
              - zip -r my-deploy.zip . -x *.git* bitbucket-pipelines.yml
            artifacts:
              - my-deploy.zip
        - step:
            name: Deploy to testing - Update Lambda code
            deployment: Test
            trigger: manual
            script:
              - pipe: atlassian/aws-lambda-deploy:0.2.3
                variables:
                  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
                  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
                  AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
                  FUNCTION_NAME: $LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME
                  COMMAND: 'update'
                  ZIP_FILE: 'my-deploy.zip'
```